# Prestashop Geoip module - missing country

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

No matter how I try I can't find Germany under GeoIP module list in Prestashop 1.6.1.7.
Country is turned on in Localization-> Countries.
I have uploaded newest GeoLiteCity.dat but that hasn't solved the problem.
Any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 1):

You may have deleted 'Germany' from the countries list on your PrestaShop, you can add it manually under Localization -> Countries in the back office.

Click on 'Add new country' button in the top right corner to open the add new country form and use data in the attached image to fill the form.

Comment: Country was present on that list. I have turned it off and on and now it works!